# why do I get an error,when I use the [over()] function in [sp] package in [R]

Tags: r, r-sp, terra

when I use `over()`, the following error showed:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
Function 'over' tag 'SpatialPointsDataFrame', 'SpatVector' could not find inheritance method


coordinates(ht.dat) <- c("x","y") 
proj4string(ht.dat) <- proj4string(bioms.shp) 
ht.dat$biome <- over(ht.dat, bioms.shp)$BIOME
ht.dat <- as.data.frame(ht.dat)
table(ht.dat$biome)
```

[class(biome.shp) is SpatVector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HENP.jpg)
[class(ht.dat) is SpatialPointsDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACPvo.jpg)

I guess that the class of *biome.shp* is wrong. If the type of *biome.shp* can be changed to SpatialPolygons, this problem can be solved, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your data?

Comment: Have you tried `as(bioms.shp, "Spatial")`?